# Adding a few Chinese characters in document of classicthesis template

Tags: languages, classicthesis, cjk

This minimal example of how to use the CJK package, as instructed [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Chinese) works perfectly on my system:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
你好
You can mix latin letters and chinese.
\end{CJK}
\end{document}
```

However, as I inserted the part with `\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}` and `\end{CJK}` with a short sentence in Chinese in between to my document, the compiler (pdflatex) complained and threw a bunch of `Undefined control sequence....` errors pointing to the line right after `\end{CJK}`.

The document I'm working on is a slightly tweaked version of `classicthesis` (supported by `arsclassica`). Most of the content are in French, so I included some more packages (mostly to have guillmets « » and the spacing between the colon, question mark and exclamation mark to be correct.

The packages included with their options are:

```
\usepackage [%eulerchapternumbers,%eulermath,drafting,
listings,listsseparated,beramono,pdfspacing,%listings,
                    subfig,parts,dottedtoc]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[french]{arsclassica}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[american,french]{babel}

%For French quotation:
\usepackage[french=guillemets]{csquotes}


%For a few chinese words:
\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{french}

des langues étrangères appliquées et d'effectuer le travail à l'hôtel...     
Bien que j'aie rencontré des difficultés car ce sont mes...

\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
文章
\end{CJK}
des langues étrangères appliquées et d'effectuer le travail à l'hôtel...

\end{document}
```

Error: `Undefined control sequence. des langues é`

`Undefined control sequence. des langues étrangè`

EDIT: if the whole content is only in English (i.e. no character with accent á è é à... ) then it compiles without problem. Before CJK environment starts the compiling is all find, but right after the `CJK` environment ends, the compiler starts to complain about the French characters with accent:

(in my "complete" version, it did not even export the output -- perhaps it stopped after too many errors)
[image]

So I guess the reason is behind the documentclass which classicthesis is based on, or some other settings with the font etc., but I don't know to to fix this. How do I change the options of the included packages or change the .sty files to include a Chinese sentence between the French content?

Comment: Why do you expect from us to extend your snippets to something we can try? Make a *complete* example that demonstrates the error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer edited with example :)

Comment: This doesn't compile, a \documentclass command is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error can be easily reproduce in a simple example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%For a few chinese words:
\usepackage{CJK}

\begin{document}

des langues étrangères 


\begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
文章
\end{CJK}

des langues étrangères 

\end{document}
```

The solution is to use either

```
\usepackage[encapsulated]{CJK}
```

or the newer

```
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
```

instead of `CJK`.

Comment: The documentclass is "scrreprt" but this works! Thanks ;)

Comment: Adding "encapsulated" does not work, still having *Undefined control sequence* errors after the end tag